# A function $f: \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^2}=L>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, functions

Consider a function $f: \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^2}=L>0$. Prove that $f$ isn't surjective.
Well, I suppose that the only way to go about proving this is by contradiction, but I couldn't make much progress. All I could come up with was writing the definition of a limit and I got that $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists n_\epsilon \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\left|\frac{f(n)}{n^2}-L\right|<\epsilon, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}, n \ge n_\epsilon$.
Expanding gives us that $n^2(L-\epsilon)<f(n)<n^2(L+\epsilon), \forall n\ge n_\epsilon$ and now I am stuck, since I don't know how to use the fact that I assumed that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: If $f(n) \geqslant cn^2$ for $n \geqslant n_0$, where $c > 0$, then $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{f(n) + 1} < +\infty\,.$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $f$ have the desired limit. There is an $N_1\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n\geq N_1$, $f(n) > \frac{L}{2} n^2$. There is an $N_2$ such that $LN_2>2$. In particular, if $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$, for $n>2N$ we have $$f(n) >  L N(n-N)>  2(n-N)$$In other words, $f$ 'skips' integers infinitely often. Note that $f([N])=f(\{1,2,\ldots,N\})$ is finite, so the first few cases can't rectify this. Thus $f$ is not surjective.

Thanks to DanielFischer for noticing an error and providing guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another point of view : Take $\epsilon=L/2$ then you know that $f(n)>n^2L/2$ for all $n\geq n_\epsilon$. Therefore
$$n\geq |f^{-1}(\{1,2,\dots,\left\lfloor\frac{n^2L}{2}\right\rfloor\})|\geq \left\lfloor\frac{n^2L}{2}\right\rfloor$$
for all $n\geq n_\epsilon$. By making $n\to\infty$ you get a contradiction.